# php include misconfiguration on centOS

Tags: php, centos, include-path

We set up a new dedicated server with centOS & Plesk 11 but there is weird issue like on require_once function when I call the file with "./" there is no problem but when I use one slash "/" to call a file in a path relative to root it does not work and I get no error.

I tried to modify include_path by giving the pear's path and ope_basedir options in the php configuration, it did not work.

I cannot use any global variables to fix it because there is tons of script which use require function this way. I need do it by changing the server configuration

How can I fix this issue or why it's happening?

I would be glad if you could hep.

Best Regards

Comment: strange, usually it's the other way round: absolute paths work but relative paths are borked. Just for clarification: by `when I use one slash "/" to call a file in a path relative to root` you mean absolute paths like `/usr/home/volker/some.file` i.e.s tarting at the root node of the filesystem?

Comment: @VolkerK sorry by relative to root, I mean /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs folder